# HTML frame - image source- QGIS

Tags: qgis, image, html, atlas, insert

In my shapefile, a field name is "photo", which has list of photos, the photos and my shapefile and project file are located in same folder. I would like to prepare atlas, I tried different options from different users mentioned in various tutorials, but image was not displayed.

```
'<img src="file:///D:/Projects2022/SenseImage/StreetVendor_mergePhoto_work/SurveyTest3/"||  "PHOTO"  ||""width=250">'
'<img src="D:\Projects2022\SenseImage\StreetVendor_mergePhoto_work\SurveyTest3"||  "PHOTO"  ||""width=250">'
'<img src="D:/Projects2022/SenseImage/StreetVendor_mergePhoto_work/SurveyTest3"||  "PHOTO"  ||""width=250">'
```

Answer (score 4):

Since the shapefile is used as a coverage layer for the atlas and the photos are stored in the same folder, no need to add the full path to your photos in the `<img src =`. Another issue I noticed is that you forgot to add a forward slash `/` before closing the tag `/>`.

The `Photo` field stores the photo names in the attribute table of the coverage layer as follows:

[image]

Using the following expression in the `HTML box`:

```
'<img src = "' || "Photo" ||'"' || ' width="100%"/>'
```

will do the job:

[image]

Here is the result:

The first point in the coverage layer:

[image]

The second point in the coverage layer:

[image]

The photos are updated based on the point shapefile used as a coverage layer.